# File types change into .xml while downloading in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my asp .net application we can upload doc files and after uploading files we can view it in browser. It is working in all browser, but there is one issue while view through Firefox, while clicking hyperlink view the file is being download, but file type changes into .xml (xml extension). So there is problem while open it. We can open it by making some changes in firefox settings but its not practical to do so in all clients machine. It was working in previous version firefox. And also still working in all other browser like Chrome and IE, and downloads in same file type while clicking hyperlink View. How can I download the files as its original file type in firefox.  Please help me

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking about. Is this a programming question? If it is, see my next comment.  If it is not: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I  developed an asp .net application. Its just working right before updating Firefox. After updating Firefox its working but while downloading the doc files are changed into xml(xml extension) so while open with MS 2010 im getting error like this
" Other files Exist
The selected locations do not contain pictures to preview,but other files exists.
To view these files on the View menu click show picture only "
What I have to do in order to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the [MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) to `Response.ContentType` correctly? E.g.:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Also I remember Firefox having a problem with spaces in filenames - you had to escape them. So it might be your extension is getting cut off. But that was years ago, might not be relevant anymore. 
You can check it out anyways:

Incorrect:
`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));`

Correct:
`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));`